# How to build a C array like this dynamically in a loop, return it, and keep a reference?

Tags: objective-c, c, arrays, memory-management, multidimensional-array

Right now I have this setup:

An NSMutableArray which stores two NSMutableArray instances.

A for-loop walks over a set of data and writes values into these arrays. It's for a big diagram / chart which is going to be displayed with OpenGL ES.

The NSMutableArray containing two other NSMutableArray objects is returned by a method, and the caller assigns it to a retaining property.

The pitty is this: There can be up to 2.000 values, and I don't like to create all those NSNumber objects.

Now I hope there's a lightweight way to do this with C.

Before I walk the loop I know the number of data points.

Now I want to refactor this so that I get lightweight C-arrays that hold just plain old float values. I know how to create a C-array of float values, but not really dynamically:

```
CGFloat values[ ] = {
    0, 2.5f,
    30.2f, 2.5f,
    50.95f, 200.55f,
    930.2f, 122.1f,
};
```

Questions:

1) How can I create an array like this dynamically in a loop?

2) How would I put two of those arrays into one array?

3) What about the memory managament? The method returns that multidimensional C-array, and the receiver needs to assign that to an instance variable (property). It needs to be kept around for a while. How could I create an instance variable to hold such an C-array, without knowing it's exact size in advance?

Comment: If you want a C answer, you should probably remove the Objective-C tag, as they're different languages...

Comment: No. I want to store a C-array in a Objective-C class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first question, you can dynamically create an array using `malloc()`, and use a pointer variable to store a reference to the first element of it.  For example, this will create an array of 8 `CGFloat`s:

```
CGFloat *a = malloc(8 * sizeof a[0]);
```

If `a` is non-NULL, you can then access `a[0]` through `a[7]` in the usual way.  You can return this `CGFloat *` value to another function, and when you are done with the array, you must pass this value to `free()`.

For second question, you can create an array of two pointers to the two dynamic arrays:

```
CGFloat *a[2] = { NULL, NULL };

a[0] = malloc(8 * sizeof a[0][0]);
a[1] = malloc(16 * sizeof a[1][0]);
```

You can now access `a[0][0]` through `a[0][7]` and `a[1][0]` through `a[1][15]` (as long as `a[0]` and `a[1]` are not `NULL`).

However, there is a wrinkle here: You cannot directly return arrays in C, so you cannot return `a` from a function anymore.  You *could* instead use two levels of dynamic arrays, but it probably makes more sense to store the array of pointers within the retaining object in the first place, and pass a reference to this array to the function that fills it in.

This means that your containing object would include the `CGFloat *a[2]` field, and your function that allocates the dynamic arrays and fills them would include a `CFloat *dest[]` parameter.  That function would start with something like:

```
dest[0] = malloc(8 * sizeof dest[0][0]);
dest[1] = malloc(16 * sizeof dest[1][0]);
```

...and then fill in the values as normal.

For the third question, the array that is created by `malloc()` will live until that pointer is later passed to `free()`.  As mentioned, you can happily return that value and store it elsewhere, as long as you don't `free()` it until you're done with it.

Answer (score 3):

This will get you a new array:

```
CGFLoat* myArray = malloc(numberOfFloat * sizeof(float));
```

You can do things like `myArray[6] = 0;`.

When you're done with it, you have to call `free(myArray)`, or you will have a memory leak.

With this in mind, your instance variable will just be a `CGFloat*`.